# How to properly use version control tag in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, version-control, azure-pipelines

Thats my current yml file:

```
pool:
  name: Azure Pipelines
steps:
- task: Docker@2
  inputs:
    containerRegistry: 'blabla'
    repository: 'blabla'
    command: 'buildAndPush'
    Dockerfile: '**/Dockerfile'
    buildContext: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)'
    tags: |
      test_1.$(Build.BuildId)
      latest
```

I want my tag to be:
test_1.0, then
test_1.1 ...
For every execution of the pipeline.
The $(Build.BuildId) seems to return the execution of all pipelines, so its a huge number.
How can i do this?

Comment: Can you use other variables available in devops like  $(DayOfYear) ? If you use  $(DayOfYear) every year, it will be repeated , But you can find more avilable varibales and concat together ,Ref https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/run-number?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#tokens

Comment: This is an issue of generating semantic version numbers. Look into integrating a tool like GitVersion into your pipeline to automatically manage semantic versioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to properly use version control tag in Azure Devops

You can define your own counter for the tag, like:

```
variables:
  internalBuildNumber: 1
  semanticBuildNumber: $[counter(variables['internalBuildNumber'], 0)]

- task: Docker@2
  inputs:
    containerRegistry: 'blabla'
    repository: 'blabla'
    command: 'buildAndPush'
    Dockerfile: '**/Dockerfile'
    buildContext: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)'
    tags: |
      test_1.$(semanticBuildNumber)
      latest
```

In this case, we can control the increase of the label for every execution of the pipeline.